# How to fetch a report generated by findbugs on Jenkins server?

Tags: java, rest, jenkins, findbugs, jenkins-api

I need to maintain a record of how many bugs are introduces or reduced after some checkin with automation for which I need access to the reports generated by FindBugs.

I am able to get the report of SonarQube using rest API but I can't figure out a way to do the same for FindBugs.

Comment: Are you running FindBugs as part of your SonarQube analysis or independently?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to ascertain @slartidan. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question of course has to be: why bother about FindBugs, if you have SonarQube (that already provides most of Findbug's rules)? :)

Besides that: You can download files via jenkin's HTTP API. The URL for to retrieve workspace resources is something like this:

```
http://<server>/job/<job>/ws/<path to file>
```

so for example:

```
http://jenkins.server:1234/job/my_job/ws/my_project/target/findbugs.xml
```